# How to double a value if its a string within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to find the half of the value if the ID is even and for every ID the is odd it would be doubled.

Here is an example I did for the numbers(ID)

```js
var numbers = [8, 12, 5, 2, 5, 7];
var collectionNumbers = {
  orginialNumbers: numbers,
  doubledNumbers: numbers.map(function(n) { return n * 2; })
};

console.log(collectionNumbers);
```

Simple gets the job done for multiplying numbers in general but my array looks like this:

I'm trying to figure out how to half or double the last 3 `ID`'s

```
data = [
  { ID: 1 },
  { ID: 2 },
  { ID: 33 },
  { ID: 66 },
  { ID: 'abc' },
  { ID: 'xyz' },
  { ID: 'A1' }
]
```

Im trying to figure out how to half or double the last 3 ID's

Since I have it the way I do I get undefined for the strings in the array. Which is fine, I'm mostly concerned about for the strings do I have to convert then to numbers to half or double the value. If so how would I do that with a string?

Comment: please add your wanted result.

Comment: What is half or double of a string, or anything that is not a number? Same question with odd or even, it is nonsensical when it comes to anything that is not a number.

Comment: For the string values to be honest I'm not sure what double or half the value would be if the length is even or odd

Comment: Then we really cant help you lol. We could all come up with a different way to halve or double a string. Maybe share what you are trying to achieve then (why are you halving and doubling strings?) then someone may be able to help.

Comment: Try `.map((value) => isNaN(value) ? value : value % 2 === 0 ? value /2 : value * 2)`

Comment: @Rajesh are you putting that with doubledNumbers if so it returned the strings as they were and just doubled the numbers

Comment: @Saenz Its not about what I am doing. What exactly do you want to happen if the value is string? Should it be concatinated? Should half of it be striped if index is even? Your requirements are unclear.

Comment: Im not sure why the data is like that, that is just the way the wanted it for some reason

Comment: @Rajesh for all the ID's in the data array I'm trying to loop all of them to 1st see if its even or odd if so half the value for every even ID and double or every odd ID

Comment: @Saenz You still didn't answer the important question. A string is neither odd nor even. What should happen to that?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speculating that if it's a string then concatenate the string to itself if the length odd otherwise get the first half of the string you can use the following.

If this is homework (as I suspect), the real lesson is to get clear and unambiguous requirements.

```js
var data = [
{ID:1},
{ID:2},
{ID:33},
{ID:66},
{ID:"abc"},
{ID:"xyz"},
{ID:"A1"}
]

var modded = data.map(function(o){
  //Set a variable to return
  var retval = o.ID
  //If it's a number
  if(typeof o.ID === "number") {
    //Halve it if even, otherwise double it
    retval = o.ID % 2 === 0 ? o.ID / 2 : o.ID * 2;
  //otherwise
  }else{    
    //if the string length is even, get the first half of the string, otherwise add the string to itself
    retval = o.ID.length % 2 === 0 ? o.ID.substring(0, o.ID.length /2) : o.ID + o.ID
  }  
  
  return retval;
});

console.log(modded);
```

Comment: yes this is what I was looking for. Next time I will for sure ask for more detail for sure. Thank you